# Showing element in default.ctp

Tags: database, cakephp, element, default

I would like to know,

1. Can I display a database record in an element..?.
2. Can I add an element (which is containing the database record) in default.ctp..?.

Comment: you shouldn't be inserting records into the DB in an element

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you [read](http://book.cakephp.org/view/879/Beginning-With-CakePHP) the [user guide](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog), as all of this can be done with minimal effort after a basic understanding of Cake conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the manual of CakePHP this are the basics steps to programming with CakePHP.
Here you can see how to work with [elements](http://www.florian-hacquebart.eu/?p=134)

Good Luck